angular nx monorepo custom env variables not defined
I am following the instructions presented in the following document: https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/use-environment-variables-in-angular and it seems to be half working, but in an odd way. I get the following error when I try to access the value of my variable: blah is not defined wherein blah comes from my project.json defined at the root of my project in the project.json.
"define": {
          "API_URL_OVERRIDE": "blah"
        },

I then tried to change it such that I created my types in the root of my project and I added the following in the libs/users/feature folder where my tsconfig for the particular library lives as so:
"files": ["../../../types/types.d.ts"],
This makes my compiler happy, but when I run npx nx serve my-project I get Cannot find name 'API_URL_OVERRIDE'
So what exactly is the correct way to add env variables via nx for angular as clearly their documentation is either wrong or it is omitting something in some erroneous assumption that people know what the missing steps (like how every math book says "it is elementary" to figure out this complex derivative)
